# Is it possible to make nodes out of webform submissions?

Tags: drupal, nodes, drupal-webform

Essentially, I'd like to have a webform submission automatically create a node from the contents of its submission (Drupal 7). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duh. I should have put this on [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/). My bad. Anyway, two answers over there:

1. [How to create a node with submissions of a webform?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/80022/how-to-create-a-node-with-submissions-of-a-webform)
2. [Webform submission as new node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/83671/webform-submission-as-new-node)

Answer (score 0):

Well there is this hook:
[hook_webform_submission_insert](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!webform.api.php/function/hook_webform_submission_insert/7)

Inside that hook you can create a new node using the `$submission` parameter that contains the submission just saved in the database.

To create a new node you can use [node_save](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_save/7) api